# How can I configure Databricks display function to visualize Pyspark Decision tree with original feature names?

Tags: pyspark, data-visualization, databricks, decision-tree, azure-databricks

My objective is to visualize a Pyspark regression decision tree in Databricks.

There is a display function `display(decision_tree)` in Databricks which helps in visualization of decision tree (https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/visualizations/index.html#id15).

[Sample decision tree printed by `display(decision_tree)` in Databricks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sblz7.png)

Pyspark decision tree requires that all features are in a list under a single feature name called "features". Hence, we see the feature names as feature 1, feature 2 etc.

Let's say the original feature names are in a list called `cols`. Is there a way to modify the feature names in the sample decision tree to the original feature names while visualization using `display(decision_tree)` function?